# Build a CodeStar pipiline that spans two different AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit, aws-codestar

For the same project, I have two separate account a `dev` account and a `staging/production` account.

On the first, each developer has full access on all account's services. There's a CodeStar service in place, when a push is made on the related CodeCommit the Pipeline starts and goes on until the code itself is deployed.
When dev team is OK with their works, they can branch the main line to mark a release ready for the stage/production.

When a new release needs a staging step, business should choose what branch wants to deploy in stage. So with a single click code should be pulled from the first account builded and deployed in this staging account (the latter).

- How can I make something like that?
- How can I start the staging pipeline from the CodeCommit source of another account?
- I would use CodeStar in the latter account too (so I can use the dashboard), can I? Or I should start with a custom workflow?

Any given suggestion is appreciated, I haven't seen best practice on the web.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this so far? I'd be looking for something very similar, minus the different accounts, but I can work with that as well.

Comment: No progress, project in stand by :)